# AWK different versions behavior when using regex pattern

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, libopencm3

**Background:**

Recently I have tried to build [libopencm3-examples](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3-examples) on Ubuntu 14.04 and encountered a build error (while for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS it works ok). I started digging in order to find the reason. As I have discovered, libopencm3 uses specific linker script generator:

see `libopencm3-examples/libopencm3/ld/README`

the purpose of this tool is to pass target micro controller specific defines to linker script template. So it use preprocessor under template script and pass target specific parameters like so:

```
-D_FPU=hard-fpv5-sp-d16 -D_ROM_OFF=0x08000000 -D_RAM_OFF=0x20000000
```

to retrieve this parameters awk script is used.

```
./libopencm3/scripts/genlink.awk
```

for generating -D_XXX keys this script operates under device database `./libopencm3/ld/devices.data` 
like so:

```
awk -v PAT="$(DEVICE)" -v MODE="DEFS" -f $(OPENCM3_DIR)/scripts/genlink.awk $(OPENCM3_DIR)/ld/devices.data
```

**Question:**

The awk script part, extracting the defines info from database looks like this:

```
...
for (i = 3; i <= NF; i = i + 1) {
...
    else if ($i ~ /[[:upper:]]*=/) {
        if ("DEFS" == MODE)
            printf "-D_%s ",$i;
    }
}
```

the row in database, processed by the script:

```
stm32f3[01]3?c* stm32f3ccm ROM=256K RAM=40K CCM=8K
```

What confuse me, is that the proposed pattern (`/[[:upper:]]*=/`) should match [ROM]=256K f.e., but not ROM=256K (yes?). Anyhow, as i already mentioned `/[[:upper:]]*=/` works for ubuntu 16.04 (GNU Awk 4.1.3) (Why?), while for 14.04 i needed to change `/[[:upper:]]*=/` -> `/[:upper:]*=/` to force it work (is this a bug or what?). Am I missing something?

Comment: I doubt if `/[:upper:]*=/` would even work as you claim, please see https://regex101.com/r/av6dGz/1

Comment: @Inian you could check it by awk, it works

Comment: It certainly does *something* but not what you describe or expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the square bracket character is special in regex.  If you want to match it literally, use `\[`.  The expression `[:upper:]` inside square brackets refers to the character class consisting of upper-case characters.  I'm guessing you want

```
/[][:upper:][]+=/
```

to form a bracket expression consisting of literal closing square bracket, uppercase characters, and literal opening square bracket.  Notice also the switch to `+` instead of `*` to prevent matching on a lone equals sign (`*` means zero or more, so with zero repetitions, it would match on any equals sign).

Possibly the Awk you have doesn't support POSIX character classes at all.  Then, you could replace `[:upper:]` with `A-Z` though it won't then match locale-sensitively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you, please, specify what is the difference between /[:upper:]*=/ and /[[:upper:]]*=/ patterns. What will be matched by the first and by second? Or there is no difference?

Comment: The regex `/[:upper:]/` matches a single character which can be colon, u, p, e, or r, and would be better written `/[:epru]/`.  The POSIX character class `[:upper:]` can only be used *inside* a regex character class (i.e. another pair of square brackets) so `/[[:upper:]]/` matches a single uppercase character.

Comment: Maybe see also http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html